# Data warehouse testing checklist

Tags: data-warehouse-testing, sql

What are some best practice approaches such as:

- SCD type 1/2/3
- nulls
- duplicates
- missing data
- extra data
- special characters
- FK/PK referential integrity.etc

Comment: Please check related question http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1212/how-far-would-you-go-in-etl-and-data-warehouse-testing/1698#1698

Answer (score 2):

I found this to be a useful, though high level article about data validation.

It's more about how to approach the testing than specific tests, but it does contain some specific tests and has a lot of useful information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg261774.aspx.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this article gives a good overview of the different data warehouse testing that should be applied:
http://quality-gates.com/?p=1284
We are using this method in almost every data warehouse project.

Comment: Welcome to SQA, uzi. Could you provide a short summary of the method provided in the link, and where applicable, provide your personal experience and how you interpreted the method?